# Cannot include ifstream "fatal error: 'ifstream' file not found"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, include

Something really weird is happening here. I've made a very simple test bit of code to include an if stream and I get a fatal error: 'ifstream' file not found on compilation. I'm suspecting it's something to do with the compiler.

```
#include <ifstream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout <<"hello world" <<endl;
}
```

the above was compiled with clang using the command clang++ *.cpp -o "test".

Comment: What is an if stream?

Comment: @ColeJohnson http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrong header name, there is no `ifstream` header. If you want to use `cout` you probably meant to include `iostream`:

```
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: I think they wanted `iostream`, because then they're trying to use `cout`.

Comment: Right, I didn't even read the rest of the snippet when I saw "<ifstream>" :) I'll edit the answer, thanks

Comment: I wanted to write to file - the hello world was just a test bit of code to see if it would run